# in Hibernate how to produce mix of mysqlmyisam and innodb tables?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I want to have some of my tables as innodb(which I have currently) and only 2-3 specific tables to be mysqlmyisam.Is there some annotation that we can use for an specific entity to become mysqlmyisam?on internet there is not much info I could find.